# initialize': rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, poltergeist

I keep getting this error while switching from Selenium over to `PhantomJs/Poltergeist`. 
Anybody know what I'm doing wrong? If I switch out the driver to selenium, the script works perfectly. Whenever I comment out the `default_driver = :selenium` and replace with `javascript_driver = :poltergeist` I run into this error.

```
initialize': rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given (ArgumentError)
```

This is all in a ruby file, no rails.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require "open-uri"
# require "date"
# require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
# require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'pry'
require 'phantomjs'
# require 'database_cleaner'

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
# Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'https://www.sameplsite.com'


module MyCapybaraTest
  class Test
    include Capybara::DSL

    def login_site
        visit('https://www.sameplsite.com')
        # binding.pry
        click_link('Log in')
        fill_in('email', :with => 'joefrank@sharklasers.com')
        fill_in('password', :with => 'passwordpassword')
        check('checkbox_remember')
        click_button('Log in')
    end

    def click_right_game
        click_link('Create Contest')
        all('.boxed')[1].click
        check('Free practice')
        click_link('Create 1 Head-to-Head')
        save_and_open_page
    end

    def output_game_link
        url = URI.parse(current_url)
        puts url
    end

  end
end


t = MyCapybaraTest::Test.new
t.login_fanduel
t.click_right_game
t.output_game_link
```

Answer (score 5):

`Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist` doesn't switch the driver. If you want to switch driver , use `Capybara.current_driver` instead. 
That says : `Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist`